# Application stopped working unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display the name and number of a contact from android phone book, i have one contact stored in my AVD. can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code please...it is showing application stopped working Please try again...thanks in advance...

```
public class get extends Activity {
        private void getColumnData(Cursor cur)
    {
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            int numi=cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);
            int namei=cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
            String name,num;
            do{
                name=cur.getString(namei);
                num=cur.getString(numi);

            }while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri u=People.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] proj=new String[]{People.NAME,People.NUMBER};
        Cursor cur=managedQuery(u, proj, null, null, null);
        getColumnData(cur);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("First step");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please us the 'code' button to format code (the one with all the little 0's and 1's)...it just indents everything by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;

Also put READ_CONTACTS permission in the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

import android.provider.ContactsContract; 
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;

ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

```
Uri uri=Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

String [] projection=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor c=managedQuery(uri,null, null, null, null);
String[] from=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
int[] to=new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
SimpleCursorAdapter sAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Also put

in the manifest file